# Nested v-for loop on firestore data reactively duplicates deepest layer on changes

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I have nested data in firestore, and I want to represent this as a nested list. However, when I change a value in the firestore database, the second level of values are not updated.

On load it looks correct:
[image]

But when I change "Temperature1" to "Temperature", it updates like this:
[image]

If I reload the page it all loogks correct again:
[image]

If I change the top level name, e.g. Cactus, it behaves as expected (the name gets updated reactively).

**How can I get the second level strings to also be simply reactively updated without duplication??**

This is my data structure in firestore: (id are auto generated ids)

```
-users (collection)
|-id0 (doc)
 |-name: "Niels"
 |-tiles (collection)
  |-id1 (doc)
  | |-name: "Monstera Deliciosa"
  | |-services (collection)
  |   |-id2 (doc)
  |   | |-name: "Temperature"
  |   |-id3 (doc)
  |     |-name: "Relative-humidity"
  |-id4 (doc)
    |-name: "Cactus"
    |-services (collection)
      |-id2 (doc)
        |-name: "Soil moisture"
```

Here are excerpts of my code:

My Vue component (which is the main view): Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <ul v-for="tile in tiles" :key=tile.id>
            <li>{{ tile.name }}</li>
            <ul v-for="service in tile.services" :key=service.id>
                <li>{{service.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['tiles'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.use(Vuex)

// handle page reload
fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        // realtime updates from tiles
        fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).collection('tiles').orderBy('name', 'asc').onSnapshot(tilesSnapshot => {
            let tilesArray = []

            tilesSnapshot.forEach(tileDoc => {
                let tile = tileDoc.data()
                tile.id = tileDoc.id
                // console.log("Tile name:", tile.name)

                let servicesArray = []
                tileDoc.ref.collection('services').onSnapshot(servicesSnapshot => {
                    servicesSnapshot.forEach(serviceDoc => {
                        let service = serviceDoc.data()
                        service.id = serviceDoc.id
                        servicesArray.push(service)
                    })
                })
                tile.services = servicesArray
                tilesArray.push(tile)
            })
            store.commit('setTiles', tilesArray)
        })
    }
})

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tiles: []
    },
    mutations: {
        setTiles(state, val) {
            if (val) {
                state.tiles = val
            } else {
                state.tiles = []
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your problem ("when I change a value in the firestore database, the second level of values are not updated") comes from the fact that Firestore has shallow reads.

Your first `onSnapshot()` listens to the results of the following query:

```
fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).collection('tiles').orderBy('name', 'asc')
```

And querying for documents in a collection **doesn't pull in data from subcollections**. Consequently, the first `onSnapshot()` triggers when you change a doc in the `tiles` collection, but does not trigger when you change a document in the `services` sub-collection.

Comment: Ahh yes, so when the deep value (service.name) gets changed, the "tiles" array in the store does not get updated (I just verified with Vue dev tool in browser). But how come the new values are inserted in the list as well (second image)? To remedy this I guess I will have to make an array for the tiles alone, and one for all services? That is a flat data structure in the store?